# Subaru Impreza 2012: circuit is good, bulb tests good, but won't light

Tags: electrical

I tested the connector (2-pin) with a test light, and both sockets worked. However when I plugged a tested bulb in, nothing.

What should I try next?

Comment: If the bulb works and the leads in the socket show life, the bulb isn't touching the leads is what I'd suggest.

Comment: I tomorrow I'll try using some jumpers to the bulb, but I don't think that's it. The sockets are pretty tight and the bulb snaps into the connector. Is less current required for a test light than a headlight bulb?

Comment: have you checked the ground or earth connection?

Comment: Would I do that by attaching the clip to the negative terminal and using the probe in the same way? Sorry for being an idiot.